# php and mysql insert input array

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

I have a problem with php. I will try to explain it as good and short as I possibly can and I hope you will understand what I'm trying to do.

I have this HTML form:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNYLvJ

As you see in the example from codepen, my text boxes can multiply if you click the hyperlink. But the first input should not multiply. In my inputs, I use square brackets. I'm trying to figure out the php part for this.
I want to run the result from an HTML form in my database.

So, Lets say I multiply textboxes 3 times. The query should be something like

```
INSERT INTO loot_template (item_entry, npc_entry, chance, mincount, maxcount, ffa) VALUES 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,0),
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6,1),
(3, 4, 5, 6, 7,0);
```

So how do I do this? I know that I need an foreach loop. I could fix it for one textbox if I multiply the textboxes but since i have more textboxes I'm not sure what to do.

So this is the php code that I have:

```
$npcentry = $_POST['npcEntry'];
mysqli_select_db($conn, $webdb);
foreach ( $_POST['itemEntry'] as $value) {
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO loot_template (npc_entry, item_entry) VALUES($npcentry, $value)");
}
```

as you see in this code example it uses foreach for itemEntry but I don't know how do to it for the rest of the textboxes.

Is it possible to do maybe something like:

```
foreach($_POST['itemEntry'] as $value1, $_POST['chance'] as $value2, $_POST['mincount'] as $value3)
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Listen to tadman! You don't want to be the next guy to get hacked.

Comment: Thank you for the info but right now i just want something that works. When i get it to work i can change stuff to have a better code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there will always be one of every element in the group you could do something simple like

```
foreach ($_POST['itemEntry'] as $key => $value) {
    $itemEntry = $value;
    $change = $_POST['chance'][$key];
    $minCount = $_POST['mincount'][$key];

    // do entry to db here with extra values
}
```

I would also change your js to add the counter to the other inputs as well

```
$('#container').append(
            '<div id="inputbox"><strong>Item' + counter + '</strong><br />'
            + '<input name="itemEntry[' + counter + ']' + '" type="text" placeholder="Item Entry"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="chance[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Drop Chance"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="mincount[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Mincount"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="maxcount[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Maxcount"><br>'
            + 'No<input type="radio" name="ffa[' + counter + ']" value="0"><br>'
            + 'Yes<input type="radio" name="ffa[' + counter + ']" value="1"><br></div>'
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing each group of textboxes inside of an array should make it a little easier to construct your query.

naming your form elements something like:

```
group[0][itemEntry]
group[0][chance]
group[0][mincount]
group[0][maxcount]
group[0][ffa]
```

so your JS might look something like:

```
var counter = 1;
      $(function(){
        $('#clicker').click(function(){
          counter += 1;
          $('#container').append(
            '<div id="inputbox"><strong>Item' + counter + '</strong><br />'
            + '<input name="group[' + counter + '][itemEntry]' + '" type="text" placeholder="Item Entry"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="group[' + counter + '][chance]" placeholder="Drop Chance"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="group[' + counter + '][mincount]" placeholder="Mincount"><br>'
            + '<input type="text" name="group[' + counter + '][maxcount]" placeholder="Maxcount"><br>'
            + 'No<input type="radio" name="group[' + counter + '][ffa]" value="0"><br>'
            + 'Yes<input type="radio" name="group[' + counter + '][ffa]" value="1"><br></div>'
          );
        });
      });
```

Then building your query in PHP might look like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO loot_template (item_entry, npc_entry, chance, mincount, maxcount, ffa) VALUES";

$numGroups = count($_POST['group'];

foreach($_POST['group'] as $i=>$group){
   $valueSet = "('" . 
                 $group['itemEntry'] . "','" .
                 $_POST['npcEntry'] . "','" .
                 $group['chance'] .  "','" .
                 $group['mincount'] .  "','" .
                 $group['maxcount'] .  "','" .
                 $group['ffa'] . "'" .
                "')";

    valueSet .= ($i+1 < numGroups) ? "," : ";";

   $query .= $valueSet;
}
```

Sorry, I can't run the code to test it.  There are probably some typos/syntax errors but hopefully that points you in the right direction.